# Condition number after some "non standard" transform

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Given a positive definite matrix $A$, and a diagonal matrix $B$ with positive diagonal entries, is the following inequality generally true?

$$\kappa((A + B)(I + B)^{-1}) \leq \kappa(A)$$

$I$ is an identity matrix.

It seems true for me since I cannot propose a counter example, and intuitively, when the entries of $B$ are all zeros or plus infinity, the inequality is true. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Have you tried to consider the case when $A$ and $B$ are 2 by 2 diagonal matrices with positive diagonal entries? If so, what did you get?